# Fragment's View elements are Null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've a `Selectl` host Activity class form where I instantiate my `AddHttpLinksFragment` .Just after that I call the Fragment's `getPls()` method. Everything works fine as long as I'm not calling any `View` elements (widgets, adapters) inside the Fragments's `getPls()` method. It seems that when I call this method the Fragment's View is not yet created, so it's widgets are `Null`. How can I prevent this?

Selectl.class:

```
        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        AddHttpLinksFragment fragment2 = new AddHttpLinksFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container1, fragment2, "addlinksF");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();

         AddHttpLinksFragment fragment = (AddHttpLinksFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("addlinksF");
        fragment.getPls(path);
```

AddHttpLinksFragmen.class:

```
public class AddHttpLinksFragment extends android.app.Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText httpAddressEdit;
EditText linkText;
URI uriPls;
ListView lv;
ArrayList<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
int itemPosition;
DBHttpLinks db;


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setRetainInstance(true);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addhttplinksfragment, container, false);

    // ListView init
    lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strList);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    return v;

}

// ...

public void getPls(Uri path) {

    try {
        uriPls = new URI(path.toString());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    PlsReader mPlsReader = new PlsReader(uriPls);
    strList.addAll(mPlsReader.Read());

   arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();     // <--- ANR, line 233
    TextView tv = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView_long_press); // <--- ANR
    tv.setText(getString(R.string.long_press_to));   // <---ANR
}

// ...

}
```

logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.Selectl}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.krisk.astream.AddHttpLinksFragment.getPls(AddHttpLinksFragment.java:233)
```

Comment: which line is `AddHttpLinksFragment.java:233`

Comment: It is commented `arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();     // <--- ANR, line 233`

Comment: try calling it in `onResume`. look at Handling the Fragment Lifecycle http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: @soulreaver your `getPls()` method and where is your textview in activity xml or fragment xml?

Comment: textview is in fragment.xml, `getPls()` method works fine.

Comment: @soulreaver then your initialization of textview is wrong. you should use the inflated view object in `onCreateView` to initialize textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fragment don't has a view displayed `onCreateView` is not called. So arrayadapter is null and this line is not called:

```
 arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strList);
```

UPDATE:

Put this on your `onCreateView`

```
 TextView tv = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView_long_press); 
tv.setText(getString(R.string.long_press_to));
```

Change your method to look like this:

```
public void getPls(Uri path) {

    try {
        uriPls = new URI(path.toString());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    PlsReader mPlsReader = new PlsReader(uriPls);
    strList.addAll(mPlsReader.Read());


}
```

create a `onResume`

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first

    if (strList != null) {       

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strList);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: `fragment.getPls(path)` is called from `Selectl.class`

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes, and it must be called from there.

Comment: do it in `onResume` of your activity class and try and move the initialization of textview in framgent to `onCreateView`. Declare textview as class member. like  `tv =  (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_long_press)`

Comment: @Dyna `onResume` is in fragment or in activity class?

Comment: in the activity @Raghunandan. I haven't tested the solution but I think it can help him.

Comment: @Dyna i misunderstood your previous comment sorry!

Answer (score 1):

From your comments you say you have textview in your fragment xml

So you need to initialize textview with the inflated view object in `onCreateView`

```
TextView tv ;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setRetainInstance(true);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addhttplinksfragment, container, false);
    lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    tv =  (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_long_press);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strList);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    return v;

 }
```

Call `getPls(path)` in `onResume`.

```
Resumed

The fragment is visible in the running activity.
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html